# Reverse Proxy using apache

Tags: apache, http, iis, nginx, reverse-proxy

Is it possible to use apache with modsecurity as a reverse proxy infront of  nginx / microsoft-iis ? Or it just works for apache to apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use apache as a reverse proxy in front of any webserver.

To answer your question: You can reverse proxy from apache to nginx/iis.